# \psTextFrame with origin specified does not affect the content position

Tags: pstricks

`\psTextFrame[origin={x,y}](0,0)(1,1){content}` does slide its frame's center to `(x,y)` but leave the content at `(0.5,0.5)`. Is it a bug or feature?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\psset{unit=1cm}% default unit

%\newcommand\mybox[3]{\rput(#1,#2){\psTextFrame[dimen=outer](0,0)(1,1){#3}}}

\newcommand\mybox[3]{\psTextFrame[origin={#1,#2},dimen=outer](0,0)(1,1){#3}}

\begin{document}
\pspicture[showgrid=false](3,3)
                \mybox{1}{2}{A} \mybox{2}{2}{B}
\mybox{0}{1}{A} \mybox{1}{1}{0} \mybox{2}{1}{1}
\mybox{0}{0}{B} \mybox{1}{0}{1} \mybox{2}{0}{0}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

Bonus question: To solve this, I am forced to use `\rput` (see the commented line in the above code snippet). However, I noticed that there are some white gaps (marked by red circles) between boxes as shown below. The green circle shows there is no white gap.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin` works only for real PSTricks objects which are defined as `\pst@object` and
`\psTextFrame` isn't. I cannot see your behaviour of the lines with a magnification of 6400 in avroread.

Answer (score 0):

`\psTextFrame` can be simulated by using `\psframe` and `\parbox` displaced by `\rput`. So my own solution is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\SpecialCoor
\psset{unit=1cm}% default unit

%\newcommand\mybox[3]{\rput(#1,#2){\psTextFrame[dimen=outer](0,0)(1,1){#3}}}

\newcommand\mybox[3]{
    \psframe[origin={#1,#2},dimen=outer](0,0)(1,1)
    \rput(!#1 0.5 add #2 0.5 add){#3}
}

\begin{document}
\pspicture[showgrid=false](3,3)
                \mybox{1}{2}{A} \mybox{2}{2}{B}
\mybox{0}{1}{A} \mybox{1}{1}{0} \mybox{2}{1}{1}
\mybox{0}{0}{B} \mybox{1}{0}{1} \mybox{2}{0}{0}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

Answer for the bonus question: Apparently the gaps occurs when using `psTextFrame` and when a small number passed to `dvips -D<number>`. To get rid of the gaps, pass 10000 to dvips or use `xelatex`.